# Each Instance of a Class use a Runtime declared Variable

Tags: java

I have a class that handles all my applications http requests. Multiple classes in my application use this http handler, and each instance needs to have correct credentials. 
These credentials are input by the user at run-time. Besides passing in the credentials multiple times, or copying the http handler to every class that uses it, how can I have it so each new initialization of the handler uses the same credentials?

Comment: you can use a singleton

Comment: Thanks, never come across that before.

Comment: Although I have suggested the singleton . but I personally dont like it much .. If you have to bother about thread safety then better not use this .. :S